# Java swing, how to call function on option menu click?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am currently using a joptionpane to display some choices to the user. How do I do certain actions based on the button being clicked (such as call a function) ?

```
Object[] options = {"Rematch",
                "Exit",
        "Reset Players"};
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                "Please pick an option",
                        "Chess",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        options,
                        options[2]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` will return a `int` indicating the index of the option that was choosen by the user.

That is, if the user selects `Rematch`, it will return `0`, if the user selects `Exit`, it will return `1` and if the user selects `Reset Players`, it will return `2`

You could use a `if` statement, but to be frank, a `switch` is probably just as useful...

```
int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
            "Please pick an option",
                    "Chess",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    options,
                    options[2]);

switch (result) {
    case 0:
        // Rematch
        break;
    case 1:
        // Exit
        break;
    case 2:
        // Reset players...
        break;
}
```

You may find [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) informative